# zend framework application memory usage and rendering time question

Tags: zend-framework

it would be nice to display memory usage taken by current request on the bottom of the page.

how would I go about measuring memory usage by zend app?
also - is there a way to measure rendering time?

any advice will be greatly appreciated:)

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along these lines...

In bootstrap:

```
Zend_Registry::set('startTime', microtime());
```

In layout:

```
$timeMs = microtime() - Zend_Registry::get('startTime');
$memory = memory_get_peak_usage();
echo sprintf("Eaten %s memory in %s", $memory, $timeMs);
```

Comment: thanks:) do you think memory_get_usage will do the job for memory part? at least that's what they use in Codeigniter profiler class.

Comment: actually  - I'll just display both:) Thanks Tomas.

Comment: Np. You can use both memory function the one with peak and the one without. But the without will not show accurate results as some of the variables might be already removed by "garbage collector" :)